# how MIX subtractions works with "packed" words

Tags: assembly, taocp

Im reading the Knuth's book TAOCP. And im just learning a simple math operations with registers. And there is an example of subtraction operation:

```
rA before: - | 1234 | 0| 0| 9
Cell 1000: - | 2000 |  150| 0
SUB 1000    
rA after:  + | 766  | 149 | ?
```

i understand that -1234-(-2000) = 766
but how (0 | 0)  - 150  = 149 ??

and why 9 - 0 = ?

These are "packed" words. And maybe i need to read more about them. Or can anyone explain ?

Answer (score 5):

I believe the logic goes like this:

- This MIX machine is a decimal machine; each byte holds two decimal digits.
- `rA` contains the value `- 1234 00 00 09`.
- Memory `M` contains the value `- 2000 0150 00`.
- Subtracting `M` from `rA` using plain decimal arithmetic gives 766,014,991, or `+ 0766 0149 91`.

Alternatively,

- This MIX machine is a binary machine; each byte holds eight binary bits.
- `rA` contains the value `- 04D2 00 00 09`.
- `M` contains the value `- 07D0 0096 00`.
- Subtracting `M` from `rA` using plain hexadecimal arithmetic gives 0x2FE0095F7, or `+ 02FE 0095 F7`, or in decimal, `+ 0766 0149 247` [*sic*].

So, without knowing the binary/decimalness of this particular MIX machine, we can't say for certain what the low-order byte of the result will be. It is guaranteed to be the single-byte representation of `-9`, but whether this is `91` decimal or `0xF7` binary is unknowable.

I don't have TAOCP in front of me right now to check, but I believe this logic is a pretty good explanation of the `?` that was puzzling you.